# NRZ-Level encoding problems

Tags: encoding

NRZ-Level is a polar Encoding method to encode digital data to digital signal.

**DC component**

> when the voltage level remains constant for long periods of time,
>   there is an increase in the low frequencies of the signal. Most
>   channels are band pass and may not support the low frequencies.

How to eliminate the DC-component problem using NRZ-Level encoding method?

Comment: With a high pass filter... or bandpass.

Comment: band pass filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Manchester encode the NRZ data - basically you mix data and clock via an exclusive or gate: -

[image]

To recover the data you need to recover the clock signal from the encoded data by using edge detectors and flip-flops. Once you have recovered the clock you can recover the data by once again, feeding encoded data and recovered clock through an exclusive or gate.

The main problem with Manchester encoding is that the data transmission now switches at the clock rate of the data and this means a doubling in bandwidth occupancy so, if that is a problem, other methods (such as "scrambling") are used.

Scrambling mixes the data to be sent with multiple delayed versions of the data (also via an exclusive or gate). Here's a very simple version: -

[image]

De-scrambling is done very similarly to scrambling: -

[image]

Alternatively you go to the analogue domain and modulate (extremely similar to manchester encoding). This is a massive subject with AM, FM, PM, forming the backbones.

Comment: How about the differential Manchester encoding?

Comment: It does the same but has the advantage that if the encoded data becomes inverted you can still de-encode the original data pattern.

Comment: If your data set can cope with a idle character that you can insert into idle periods you can then have the channel active at all times.  You need to scramble the signal BEFORE transmission so the average bit on state will be very close to 50%.  Recovery from a error will be hard as well.  You can also look at MFM and other Hard drive encoding systems but they are generally bipolar though bandwidth friendly.

Answer (score 0):

NRZ is almost a non-encoding encoding, in that you just throw your binary data at the line, and avoid doing anything clever with it. You cannot avoid the DC problem without doing something clever.

One popular method is Manchester Encoding, where every bit sent has zero DC component. This has more transitions than NRZ.

Another popular technique (whose name escapes me) is used in coding CDs, where extra 0 or 1 bits are added to each frame to bring the average DC value back to a constant value. This has more bits than NRZ.

You can't get owt for nowt.